# Много ajax-запросов на странице

Tags: ajax, php, post, javascript

Решил на главной сделать кнопку "Добавить в избранное" для каждой новости без перезагрузки страницы.

Избранное - типа модуля на сайте.

Визуальный пример:

```
- Добавить в избранное (id1)
- Добавить в избранное (id2)
- Добавить в избранное (id3)
- Добавить в избранное (id4)
```

К каждой новости нужно аяксом приписывать функцию:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$("#send").click(function(){
    var newsid = $("#newsid").val();            
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "favor.php",
        data: {"newsid": newsid},
        cache: false,                       
        success: function(response){...... и тд.
```

Получается плохой код. Можно ли с одним написанием одной функции выше отправлять разные данные? Ведь у всех кнопок "добавить в избранное" разные id. Как это применить? Что-то типа

```
...onclick="vote(5);"...
...function vote(i)...
```

Но как брать значения из name для отправки поста? Объясните подробнее.

Answer (score 1):

Основы jQuery, как бы.

```
<button class="news" id="send1" value="1" type="button">В избранное новость 1</button>
<button class="news" id="send2" value="2" type="button">В избранное новость 2</button>
<button class="news" id="send3" value="3" type="button">В избранное новость 3</button>
<button class="news" id="send4" value="4" type="button">В избранное новость 4</button>

$('.news').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "favor.php",
        data: {"newsid": $(this).val()},......
});
```

Comment: Кул, проверяю.
____

Как получить id? Нужно сменить класс после нажатия, типа звёздочка стала полной.

Comment: $(this).attr('id') же!

Comment: Вышло так, но не робит
 
$(".fav").click(function(){
var uid = <?php echo $u_id; ?>;   
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "favorite_add.php",
data: {"user": uid, "itemfid": $(this).val()},
cache: false,      
success: function(response){
if(response == 0){

}
}
});
return false;
});

<button style="padding-left:3px; padding-right:3px;" rel="tooltip_bottom" title="Добавить в избранное" class="fav" type="button" value="<?php echo $row_2['id'];?>"></button>

Comment: С id позже разберусь.  
Вот пхп:   
 
<?
include('bd.php');

if(!empty($_POST['user'])){
$uid = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['user']));
$id = intval(trim($_POST['itemfid']));

$result = mysqli_query($db, "тут вставляем в базу");
if($result == true){
echo 0;
}else{
echo 1;
}
}


?>

Answer (score 0):

Не обязательно делать разные значения можно просто дать всем кнопкам одинаковый class и потом с помощью js поймать клик

```
$("body").on("click",".badges",function()
```

Передать атрибуты можно просто добавив `<button id_favorite="тут само ID"></button`
и уже его передавать в ajax и делать то, что захочешь

```
data:{"id_favorite":$(this).attr("id_favorite"),}
```

Я делал так:

HTML + PHP - Вешал на кнопку id_badges и вставлял туда сам ID того, что нужно запихать в избранное

```
<a id_badges="<? echo $product_arr['id']; ?>" type_badges="add_favorites" class="favorites icons badges" <? if($product_arr['star'] == '1'){echo'id="star"';}; ?> ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span></a>
```

Сам AJAX, тут всё просто, передаю атрибуты id_badges и type_badges через POST

```
$("body").on("click",".badges",function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:"/php/deleted.php",
        data:{"id_badges":$(this).attr("id_badges"),"type_badges":$(this).attr("type_badges")},
        success:function(data){
            $(".refresh").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

PHP обработчик - Тут обрабатываю и добавляю в бд, в конце нужно еще зафигачить обновление блока

```
if($type_badges == "add_favorites"){
    $data = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT `user`,`star` FROM `product` WHERE `user`='".$user."' && `id`='".$id_badges."' LIMIT 1"));
if($data['star'] == '0'){
$star = "1";
print '<div class="alert succes alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> Добавлено в избранное</div>';
        } else if($data['star'] == '1'){
$star = "0";
print '<div class="alert succes alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Удалено из избранного</div>';
        }
mysql_query("UPDATE `product` SET `star`='".$star."' WHERE `id`='".$id_badges."'");
};
```